# Function that checks if all in Lower

Tags: javascript

I'm getting introduced to Javascript language and I have a basic function to write : it's supposed to check if every letter in a string is in lower and returns true or false according to, i've tried to write it but it returns "undefined" instead of true/false and I don't get why, here is the code :

```
var s="hello";
var toutEnMinuscules = function(s){
  var i=0;
  var x=true;
  for (i; i<s.length; i++ ){
    if(charAt(i)!==charAt(i).toLowerCase()){
      x=false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rémy! Welcome to the site! Glad to see your question is answered. Please refrain from posting answers just to thank people. Answers should contain, well, answers. If you want to thank the answerers, up vote their answers and accept (with the check mark) the one that was most useful to you. Don't edit 'solved' into the title. The check mark is for that. Have a look at the FAQ, if you wish, for more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply by,

```
var s="hello";
var isAllLower = s.toLowerCase() == s;
```

No need to iterate and check the characters one by one.

The problem with your code is, you are trying to access the function `charAt` in `window scope`. But actually it is available in the `prototype` of a `string`,

```
if(s.charAt(i)!==s.charAt(i).toLowerCase()){
//-^  -----------^
```

Answer (score 1):

> i've tried to write it but it returns "undefined" instead of
>   true/false and I don't get why, here is the code :

Reason is simple, because you are not invoking the function ;)

Secondly, your code is incorrect. `charAt` is not a global method, it is string method.

Make it

```
var s="hello";
var toutEnMinuscules = function(s){
  var i=0;
  var x=true;
  for (i; i<s.length; i++ ){
    if(s.charAt(i)!==s.charAt(i).toLowerCase()){ //observe that this line has changed to invoke a string function
      x=false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
toutEnMinuscules (s); //this line has been added to invoke the function
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
function isAllLower(str){
    return str.search(/^[a-z\s]*$/g)>-1;
}
```